# How do I keep values the same when converting from XLSX to CSV? Export to CSV with expanded numbers and not scientific notation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have an XLSX file which I am opening with Excel 2016.

This file includes a column "Code" which contains barcode values. The column has a number format of General.

Looking at this column, in the cell itself, a values will appear as 6.16611E+12; scientific notation.

In the formula bar (if I click on the cell), that same value will appear as 6161101860079.

I want to preserve the data in the "long format" (e.g. the 6161101860079 format, not the scientific notation values) when converting this XLSX to a CSV.

Currently, if I use “Save As” to save the file as a CSV, the long format values are lost. When I open the CSV with notepad, I can see that it only contains "Code" values in the 6.16611E+12 format.

How can I ensure that the values in the code column are kept as these long number values?

I have tried to format the XLSX Code column as Text before saving as CSV, but that does not change the outcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the number format in the cell to `Number` with 0 decimal places and "Use 1000 Separator" unchecked, and then save. A csv file basically saves what it "sees" in the cells.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Excel saves data in csv as it is shown in cells, as [@MGonet explained](https://superuser.com/a/1826128/1765086).

LibreOffice Calc, on the other hand, has the explicit checkbox in the Save as CSV dialog ("Save cell content as shown"), so it can behave like Excel, or save actual cell value in a CSV file.

[image]

If this checkbox is left unchecked, CSV should containg 6161101860079, regardless of number format.

Comment: Sometimes using other tools is the simplest solution.